# How to move all files from one folder of a different partition in terminal?

Tags: command-line, partitioning, mv

I am new to GNU/Linux, but I'm trying to learn it and already deleted my Windows OS (yeeeaahhhhh).

Now I've already done the operation dragging the files in Nautilus, but i wanna know how to do it in terminal.

I've tried a lot of different commands and methods but I couldn't do it in terminal.

I had a partition (sda4) named Backup with a Folder named Videos inside and I wanted to move all the files(not the folder) in it to my /home/Videos Folder.

opening the terminal in Backup in Nautilus I've tried (also tried without "~") :

```
mv -v ~/Videos/* ~/home/wagner/Videos
mv -v ~media/wagner/Backup/Videos/* ~/home/wagner/Videos
mv -v ~/media/wagner/Backup/Videos/* ~/home/wagner/Videos
mv -v ~/media/wagner/Backup/Videos/* ~/home/wagner/Videos
mv -v ~/Videos/* ~/home/wagner/Videos
```

then I opened as root:

```
sudo -H gnome-terminal
```

and tried:

```
mv -v ~/media/wagner/Backup/Videos/* ~/home/wagner/Videos
lsblk
../
cd ../
cd /media
cd wagner
cd Backup
ls -l
mv -v ~/Videos/* ~/home/wagner/Videos
cd videos
cd Videos
ls -l
cd/
cd /
cd /media
cd wagner
cd Backup
mv -v /Videos/* /home/wagner/Videos
mv -v /Videos/*.* /home/wagner/Videos
```

Couldn't do it any way. So I'm posting everything I've done to you to help me find out why I couldn't do it. What I've did wrong ?

Comment: `~` is actually your home directory, i.e. `/home/wagner`. Don't put it in front of every path.

Comment: Whats the output of `df --output=target /dev/sda4`?

Answer (score 2):

Your external disk is mounted at the location `/media/wagner/Backup`.
The directory where the files you want to copy are located is `/media/wagner/Backup/Videos`.
The destination directory is `/home/wagner/Videos` or `~/Videos`, which is the same.

Note that `~` is a synonym for `/home/YOUR_USERNAME`, i.e. `/home/wagner` in your case.

The command you want to run is this:

```
mv -v /media/wagner/Backup/Videos/* ~/Videos
```

Alternatively, if your current working directory is already `/media/wagner/Backup`, this is enough:

```
mv -v Videos/* ~/Videos
```

Answer (score 0):

The `~` is the same thing as `/home/wagner` (your HOME directory)

You said you mounted `sda4` as `Backup`, so go inside `Backup` and try:
`mv Videos/* ~/Videos`

Comment: As you are talking to a new user it might be helpful to replace "go inside `Backup`" with the actual command to accomplish this, ie `cd /media/wagner/Backup`.